# Notepad++ crashes while plugin the dll

Tags: plugins, notepad++

how to solve the dll crash notification in notepad++

```
 notify(SCNotification *notification):
 notification->nmhdr.code==1002
 notification->nmhdr.hwndFrom==20185902
 notification->nmhdr.idFrom==0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try running it [without plugins](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/?title=Command_Line_Switches#Alphabetical_list_of_supported_switches): `[install directory]\notepad++.exe -noPlugins`

This will still load the plugin menu though so that they may be ran at runtime. To fully remove all plugins you can (backup and then) remove the DLL files from `[install directory]\plugins\*.dll`

If that fixes it then you can add them back a few at a time until you figure out which one is causing the problem.

If not you'll need to use [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to determine what PID is using that because the problem is not actually from a plugin. It may be something else notepad++ is loading using [NMHDR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb775514%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a not compatible plugin can crash npp at start, so you have not clue of the problem

You can see the crashes from:
Control Panel\System and Security\Security and Maintenance\Reliability Monitor

On Windows10 if you have the option "Report problems =On" then you will find a very detailed report of npp crash at: 
C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\WER\ReportQueue\AppCrash_notepad++.exe_xxxxx\Report.wer

wer file can see with [app_crash_view](https://www.nirsoft.net/utils/app_crash_view.html) (a free utility from nirsoft)

For instance I found that plugin NppExternalLexers.dll with npp7.5 32bits crash on any Windows10.